# Using Syncignore to ignore symlink with sync.com

Tags: sync

I would like to have one filter file where I can specify certain files for synchronisation with sync.com. Is it possible?

I searched and found that I could put a .syncignore file in the root of my sync.com folder and specify files in there. I try to exclude a .fcpcache - file from imovie (it is actually a symlink) project folder but cannot get it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I also want to ignore some files in sync.com; did you resolve this?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I delete the symlink every time I close iMovie.